# ReactJS rendering [object Object] when I try to use backticks and map through my array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blueprintjs

I am using a BlueprintJS button and my code look something like this:

```js
<Button
    text={`${user.name} (${user.invoicesCount?.unresolved ?? 0}) 
            ${user.resolvingUsers.length > 0 ? "| " +
            user.resolvingUsers.map((u: any) => {
                            return u.name;
                          }).join(", ")
                      : "" }`}
/>
```

I want to wrap the `user.resolvingUsers.map()` in a span tag so I could style it. I tried to wrap it as such:

```js
<Button
    text={`${user.name} (${user.invoicesCount?.unresolved ?? 0}) 
            ${user.resolvingUsers.length > 0 ? "| " +
            <span>
                {user.resolvingUsers.map((u: any) => {return u.name;}).join(", ")}
            </span>
                      : "" }`}
/>
```

However, this return me a `[object Object]` and I am not sure why this is happening. I thought that by using `join()`, it would be converted into string?

Comment: Are you sure `u.name` is a String? can you please paste the result from logging `text`?

Comment: From my understanding is that `.join()` should turns the array (produced by `.map()`) into a string. 

For `text`, the documentation states that it is a `React.ReactNode` with a description of `Action text. Can be any single React renderable.`

Comment: The [object object] result its due to <span> tag, as cannot be inside template strings on React

Comment: @MiguelHidalgo So how can I style a string inside template strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if your Button `text` prop accepts `Elements` but it would be something like:

```
  text={<div>
      {`${user.name} (${user.invoicesCount?.unresolved ?? 0})`}
      {user.resolvingUsers.length > 0 ? (
        <>
          <span> | </span>
          <span>{user.resolvingUsers.map((u) => u.name).join(", ")}</span>
        </>
      ) : (
        0
      )}
    </div>}
```